# ionic pro live deploy: slow launching time except when initial launch from playstore/appstore

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I built an app using ionic and used ionic pro live deploy with **UPDATE_METHOD="none"**. Everything works fine: checking, downloading, extracting, and redirecting seems fine.

However, I observed that whenever I launch the app with updated version (version from ionic dashboard), the app starts very slow. Unlike when it was initially launched.

Initial launch (fresh from Playstore) takes **4s-5s.**
Launch after checking and downloading version in ionic dashboard takes **>20s**.

**The apk/ipa file was built using the source pushed in git.**

---

Here is the **ionic info**

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.1
npm        : 5.8.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

---

EDIT:
The uploaded apk was built using 
**ionic cordova build android --prod --release**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem aswell.

Live Deploy (Ionic Pro) uses the `build` script in your `package.json`.
That means, you can customize it.

A snippet of our `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod --aot",
    ...
}
...
```

The app does take much longer to build,

[image]

but the app starts 3-8 seconds faster (in my case).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Should I also change the `"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build"`

Comment: You do not need to, I think he just will use "build"

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback to this solution. Did it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried it for our 2 apps and it worked. Thanks!